# Error while trying to trim a number

Tags: javascript, trim

There is an issue with my JS function: the console throws an error whenever I run this function. I am just trying to "trim" the value that has been passed as an argument, but the console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: number.trim is not a function

The problem is with my syntax, following is the code:

```
function demo(number) {
  number = number.trim();  // This is where the issue happens...
  number = number.parseInt();
  // Rest of the code       
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `number` a `Number` object ?

Comment: A string value  @ guest271314

Comment: Can u post a fiddle?

Comment: It throws that error because the passed argument is not a string, make sure you are passing a string or casting it, try number = '' + number or String(number) before trying to trim it.

Comment: Find what is supported www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp

Comment: Check this out http://jsbin.com/varajiputo/edit?js,console

Answer (score 14):

Trim is only for string.

```
String.prototype.trim
```

Why you need a trim for number?

you can direct parse it with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

If you don't know your data like it may be sometimes string or sometime it may come as number

Then try like this

```
number = String(number).trim();
```

Answer (score 4):

`Uncaught TypeError: number.trim is not a function`

appear to indicate `number` is not `String` object. Error would also perhaps be returned at next line , as [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is not a method of `String.prototype`

If parameter passed to `demo` is `String` and expected result is `Number` , try casting `number` as `Number` object by calling `Number()` with argument `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+/g` to match digits , `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `""`

```js
function demo(number) {
  number = typeof number === "string" 
           ? Number(number.match(/\d+/g).join("")) 
           : typeof number === "number" ? number : typeof number;
  return number
}

console.log(demo(" abc 123 def 456 "), demo(7), demo([]))
```

Comment: I agree that js tends to unexpectedly show you a stack trace where the error is occurring on the line before of the actual error. But in this case is not, of course that with the code he showed he will get the parseInt error once he fixes this one but that doesn't mean is the same issue. You answer seems to fix the whole code but, what you state at the begining seems wrong (Unless i misinterpreted). You can confirm here http://jsbin.com/varajiputo/edit?js,console

Comment: @Zagen _"what you state at the begining seems wrong (Unless i misinterpreted)"_ Not certain which portion at "beginning" ? The error is `number` is not `String` ? Or `parseInt()` not being method of `String` or `Number` ? http://jsfiddle.net/9d3tLxnk/ ,  http://jsfiddle.net/9d3tLxnk/1/

Comment: It seems to me that you are stating that the error that the op has `Uncaught TypeError: number.trim is not a function` is not actually there but in the next line, where there is an obvious error as you pointed out. He obviously needs a string to use trim and and int for parseInt, but like i said, it seems that you implied that there wasn't an error with the input (if he wants to trim it is because he expects a string), not that your answer is wrong (I upvoted it), just little confusing in the first statement. It could help if you clarify that.

Comment: @Zagen `js` at Question not appear to reach `parseInt()` , or undefined method `.prseInt()` ; argument passed to `demo` , e.g., `number` appear to not be string or would reach error at `.parseInt()`

Comment: @Zagen See updated post , added "also" at second sentence

Answer (score 2):

That error message is saying basically that whatever is being passed into the method does not have a trim function. You will have to connect a debugger and verify what is being passed into the function. Whatever it is doesn't have a trim() function.